# Hosted Proxy Server

Tags: proxy, ipad

Hi I am setting up a couple of iPads for my company and I want to restrict the websites they have access to.

I believe the best way to do this is with a proxy server, I only need a few websites whitelisted and everything else blocked.

I would prefer to have the server off site. I have a website hosted with hostgator I don't think they allow it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Find an ISP that does permit it.  There are a large number of providers that let you run VMs, and do anything you want (that you can afford).

Answer (score 1):

The proxy server is probably the best solution (because iOS parental controls don't allow you to set a whitelist as far as I can tell).  Be aware of one *major* caveat though: If you let people install apps from the app store they can and will find a way around your proxy restriction.

In order to make this work you will need to combine the proxy settings with iOS "parental control" restrictions to ensure that your users are not able to break out of the sandbox you're putting them in.

---

I was inclined to close this as Not Constructive because there's really no advice we can give you beyond "you seem to be doing it right" and [what Zoredache has already said in his comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/511969/hosted-proxy-server#comment578273_511969) (find a provider that will let you do what you want in regards to running a proxy), but maybe someone will come up with a better solution than the proxy server.

Comment: Note that there are browser applications for iOS that support website whitelists ([Sandbox is one](http://floatlearning.com/mobile-learning-apps/sandbox/)) but I can't vouch for their quality, security, or suitability for use in your environment. Also they would require parental control tweaking as well...